# Why final Byte as a case in switch statement doesn't compile?

Tags: java, switch-statement, constants

```
byte a = 125;
final byte b = 2;
final Byte c = 3;
switch (a) {
case b: // works fine
    break;
case c: // Constant Expression required
    break;
}
```

Since `c`is a `final` variable, isn't it a compile time constant and hence a valid case label?

Comment: How could you execute a switch statement with a constant statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since c is a final variable, isn't it a compile time constant

No. The rules for constant expressions are given in [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), and they don't include wrapper types:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following [...]

A wrapper type is neither a primitive type nor `String`.

Comment: That is my query. Why is a byte expression considered constant but Byte expression is not, even though both are declared final?

Comment: @paidedly: Did you read JLS 15.28 which describes constant expressions?

Comment: @paidedly that's not what they mean with constant expression, how would that case work? which kind of equality would be applied if that snipper was valid code?

Comment: ok got it. So wrapper type variables can never be constant expressions. Thanks!